# Can Polymer element add an event listener to it's parent element when inside shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I would like to make a context menu element that automatically adds a `contextmenu` listener to it's parent element (so it can be expanded when the parent is right-clicked). I managed to do it by looking up `this.parentNode` when the element sits in a regular DOM hierarchy. However, when inside a shadow DOM, `this.parentNode` points to `#document-fragment` and there doesn't seem to be a way to pierce through that barrier. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? If you could post the DOM hierarchy you are testing, both when your element is positioned in light DOM and  also when it is nested within a Shadow root, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> there doesn't seem to be a way to pierce through that barrier

In Polymer, there is a `host` property on the Shadow DOM document-fragment that points to the owning element.

Comment: In some cases, it's also important to hold off access the parent element until http://www.polymer-project.org/resources/faq.html#parentnode after `attached()`.